# Syntax Error: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Syntax Error: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL` when adding `collection_check_boxes` to the views.

```
= collection_check_boxes :ethnicity, (collection: ['Asian', 'Black', 'Biracial', 'Indian', 'Hispanic/Latin', 'Middle Eastern', 'Native American', 'Pacific Islander', 'White', 'Other']), prompt: 'Ethnicity'
```

Server log:

```
 syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
..._boxes :ethnicity, (collection: ['Asian', 'Black', 'Biracial...
```

It points to `collection:` being the issue.

Comment: remove brackets `()` and all should work.

Comment: @Зелёный Brackets would be required to list options, as I have always used it that way. However I removed it to try, and new error `wrong number of arguments (2 for 5..7)`.

Comment: as you can see from error `wrong number of arguments (2 for 5..7)` you should pass 5 or 7 parameters not 2, this is nothing about brackets. [`Read documentation please`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)